# Error occurring when I open workflow - Sharepoint Designer 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I am trying to open a workflow 2013 in SharePoint Designer 2013, but is occurring an error:

> Failed to load this workflow. To correct this problem, restart Sharepoint Designer.

I have restarted the SP Designer, but when I try to open the workflow again, the same error appears.

I already cleared the cache of SharePoint and I don't have this problem with another Workflow. This error is occurring when I try to open a specific workflow.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score -1):

Check do you have latest updates to SP Designer installed (via Windows Update)

Comment: I already installed all updates and the problem is the same.

Comment: Do you get any errors on SP side via ULS logs?

Comment: MS is not updating SPD since centuries